# Handling spaces in filenames in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have this dir structure:

```
ParentDir
 |
 -- Child Dir1
     |
     -- File One.txt
     -- File
 |
 -- Child Dir2
     |
     -- File Two.txt
     -- File
```

I'm trying to find out all the `.txt` files and count the sum total of number of lines in them, so I do something like this:

```
TXTFILES=$(find . -name '*.txt')
cat $TXTFILES | wc -l
```

but the problem is, I get,

```
cat: ./Child: No such file or directory
cat: Dir2/File: No such file or directory
cat: Two.txt: No such file or directory
cat: ./Child: No such file or directory
cat: Dir1/File: No such file or directory
cat: One.txt: No such file or directory
```

How do I handle spaces in the Dir & File names in such a situation? Is it possible *without* using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat -- '{}' ';' | wc -l
```

This runs `cat` individually for each file (which is less than ideal), but the filename is passed directly from `find` to `cat` without being parsed by the shell. So the filename could be anything that's problematic on the command line.

Comment: if you use `+` instead of `;` it'll batch up the arguments to `cat` as far as possible.

Comment: This works, with the exact same output I was hoping for, and in the exact format I was expecting. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to store the file names in a variable, you can do this in 1 line:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

`find` supports a `-print0` option that makes it use a null byte, rather than a space, to separate the file names.  `xargs` supports a `-0` (hyphen zero) switch to tell it the incoming file names are separated by a null byte rather than a space.

Comment: `... | xargs -0 cat -- | wc -l` would produce output more like what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Kenster - Yes, perfect.

Answer (score 0):

dirty and quick:

```
ls -1FR|grep -c '\.txt$'
```

zsh:

```
ls **/*.txt|wc -l
```

Comment: The second will work in `bash` 4.x as well if `shopt -s globstar` is used, although in either shell you can (and should) use `wc -l **/*.txt` instead.

Comment: @chepner `wc -l **/*.txt` does something else than `ls **/*.txt|wc -l`, doesn't it?

Comment: `wc -l **/*.txt` and `cat **/*.txt | wc -l` are slightly different, although the total line length of all the files is present in the output. `ls **/*.txt | wc -l` is quite different from what the OP asked; it gives the number of matching files.

Comment: @chepner ah!!!! I misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted to have the result `ls ..|wc -l` ....my bad... pending to remove

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your files name path by " " like this

```
find . -name '*.txt' | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | wc -l
```

Example :

```
prompt$ touch a.txt "a a.txt"

prompt$ find . -name '*.txt' | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g'
"./a a.txt"
"./a.txt"

prompt$ find . -name '*.txt' | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | wc -l
2
```