# prevent space from splitting filenames using backticks

Tags: linux, command-line

Using find to select files to pass to another command using backticks/backquotes, I've noted that filenames that contain spaces will be split, and therfore not found.

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour? The command I issued looks like this

```
wc `find . -name '*.txt'`
```

but for example when there is a file named `a b c.txt` in directory `x` it reports

```
$ wc `find . -name '*.txt'`
wc: ./x/a: No such file or directory
wc: b: No such file or directory
wc: c.txt: No such file or directory
```

When used with multiple files `wc` will show the output of each file, and a final summary line with the totals of all files. that's why I want to execute wc once.

I tried escaping spaces with sed, but wc produces the same output (splits filenames with spaces).

```
wc `find . -name '*.txt' | sed 's/ /\\\ /pg'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-print0` option to `find` and the corresponding `-0` option to `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 wc
```

You can also use the `-exec` option to `find`:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec wc {} +
```

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what xargs normally does. It was created to batch the calls up into optimal groups.

Answer (score 0):

from this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079764/handling-spaces-in-filenames-in-bash) (should I flag my question as a duplicate?) I found another answer to this using bash's `**` expansion:

```
wc **/*.txt
```

for this to work I had to

```
shopt -s globstar
```